# How to get range of second 15m candle in tradingview pine editor?

Tags: pine-script

I want range breakout of the 2nd 15 minute candle, but I cant figure out how to do it.

How can I find the range of the second candle?

---

[image: I want to know how to find the range of the second candle]

Comment: Please can you provide some code examples perhaps showing what you've tried already? Otherwise it's really hard for people to help you out.

Comment: Also a little drawing would help to understand what you mean by "range breakout".

Comment: without knowing how to get the range of second candle I cant start :p like opening range breakout we use the first candle so instead of first we use second candle

Comment: It's unlclear what you mean with "2nd candle". Usually one counts candles backwards from curren one. In that case the answer is trivial: `range = high[2] - low[2]`. If that is not what you are looking for, you need to edit your question to be more specific. (What is your "beginning"?)